# odoo context field. default value for popup

Tags: python, odoo, xml-rpc, odoo-8, odoo-9

I work with Odoo(v9). I have custom: form(for model 1), action and popup with form(for model 2).
Here example main form:

```
<record id="my_id_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">my_name_form</field>
    <field name="model">my_model_one</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="Name">
            <sheet>
                <group>
                    <field name="partner_id"/>
                    <!-- button which open popup with my_model_two -->
                    <button string="Open popup"
                            name="%(my_module.action_open_popup)d"
                            type="action"
                            class="btn-link"/>
                </group>
            </sheet>
        </form>
    </field>
</record>
```

Window action for button *Open popup*:

```
<record id="action_open_popup" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">action name</field>
    <field name="res_model">my_model_two</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="model_two_form_popup"/>
    <!-- 
    How I can send partner_id from main form to popup? 
    I tried different ways in context field, but all in vain  
    <field name="context">{'default_partner_id': ?????,}</field>
    -->
    <field name="target">new</field>
</record>
```

Example *my_model_one*

```
class MyModelOne(models.Model):
    _name = 'my_model_one'

    partner_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string='Partner')
```

Popup form:

```
<record id="model_two_form_popup" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">Popup name</field>
    <field name="model">my_model_two</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="Popup text">
            <sheet>
                <group>
                    <field name="partner_id" invisible="1"/>
                <group>
            </sheet>
        </form>
    </field>
</record>
```

My question is: How I can send value *from field in main form* to *popup form*?(partner_id)

I saw how in the code used *active_id*, string or integer values. But I have not found how to send fields values or how to register method for custom logic.
Can someone provide a small example? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the solution.
In element button need to add *context* like this:

```
<button string="Open popup"
    name="%(my_module.action_open_popup)d"
    type="action"
    class="btn-link"
    <!-- name_of_parameter: name_of_field -->
    context="{'partner_id': partner_id}"/>
```

After this we need set default value to popup:

```
<record id="action_open_popup" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">action name</field>
    <field name="res_model">my_model_two</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="model_two_form_popup"/>
    <!-- set default value to field from context parameter by name -->
    <field name="context">{'default_partner_id': context.get('partner_id', False),}</field>
    <field name="target">new</field>
</record>
```

Answer (score 4):

you can do better the context could be dynamic when you use a python method to open the popup see example in the odoo addons :

```
@api.multi
def open_popup(self)
#the best thing you can calculate the default values 
# however you like then pass them to the context
return {
        'name': 'Import Module',
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'target': 'new',
        'res_model': 'model.name',
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'context':   {'default_partner_id':value,'default_other_field':othervalues},
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In view xml:

```
<field 
    name="item_ids"
    nolabel="1"
    domain="['apl_id','=',active_id]" 
    context="{'res_id':active_id}">
```

and in model.py (items):

```
_defaults = {
    "res_id": lambda self,cr,uid,c:c.get('res_id',False)
}
```